# chromehtml2pdf renders too soon. Have page load event wait for asynchronous fetch() requests to resovle?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, pdf-generation

My webpage is rendered to PDF with chromehtml2pdf, which will execute the render when the page loads (I assume on the `load` event?). This page has react elements that are loaded asynchronously, after the `load` event. I want chromehtml2pdf to wait for all of these API calls to resolve.

chromehtml2pdf doesn't seem to have much in the way of timing control. (I have moved away from tools such as wkhtmltopdf as the rendering engine is absolutely ancient and does not support the page content)

My next thought is modify the page so `load` doesn't fire until all relevant fetch() calls have resolved. How do I go about this?